# Jetty 9.3.6 and Servlet WebAppContext getServletContext() returns null

Tags: servlets, web-applications, nullpointerexception, jetty

I am missing something with this I am sure.  But I have spent the last few days searching and unfortunately I have not found an answer that seems to fit.

I have a Servlet that extents HttpServlet and overrides init()  "not init(ContextConfig)"  and in the init() function getServletContext is always returning null.  This was not the case while I was using Springs 4.0.x and Jetty 8.1.x  I would guess I am doing something wrong but at a loss as to what it is.  I have generally removed Springs from the test code, but it still gets null.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app version="3.0"  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<servlet>
    <display-name>MyServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlet.MyServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

JavaConfig Starter partial:

```
            WebAppContext root = new WebAppContext();
        root.setDescriptor("./WEB-INF/web.xml");
        root.setDisplayName("Root Context");
        root.setSessionHandler(sesh); //Persist Session across restarts of context


        root.setHandler(csh);
        root.setMaxFormContentSize(10000000);
        // Cron Servlet
        System.out.println("Checking root ServletContext ");
        if (root.getServletContext() == null) 
            System.out.println("ServletContext is null");

        //ServletHolder test = new ServletHolder(new MyServlet());
        //test.setDisplayName("test");
        //test.setName("test");
        //root.addServlet(test, "/the");


        root.setResourceBase(new File("./jsp").getPath());

        server.setHandler(root);

        //Start the server
        server.start();
        server.join();
```

And the servlet:

```
package servlet;
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MyServlet.class);

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


public void init() throws ServletException {
    // Initialization code...
    log.info("MyServlet init()");
    super.init();
    ServletContext sc = getServletContext();
    if (sc == null) 
        log.info("54: Conext returned null");
}

public void destroy() {
    log.info("MyServlet destroy()");
}

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
    resp.setHeader("Server", "GoAway");
    doProcess(req, resp);
}

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
    resp.setHeader("Server", "GoAway");
    doProcess(req, resp);
}

private void doProcess(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
    PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
    // setup no cache
    resp.setContentType("text/html");
    resp.getWriter().println("<html><head><META HTTP-EQUIV=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=/\"></head><body>\n</body>\n</html>");
    resp.getWriter().close();
    out.close();
    return;
}

protected void doTrace(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    resp.setHeader("Server", "GoAway");
    resp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED);
}
}
```

So this is something I stripped out of a larger application to figure out what I was doing wrong.  so somethings might still be un-needed.  You can see in the Javaconfig I have tried creating the servlet container there as well, but the results are the same.

So from inside the Start code the servletContext is not null.
but from inside the MyServlet init() code it is always returning null.

I really am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Thanks for your help.

o FYI included Jar's

```
commons-beanutils-1.9.2.jar
commons-codec-1.9.jar
commons-io-2.2.jar
commons-logging-1.2.jar
javax.el-2.2.6.jar
javax.el-api-2.2.5.jar
javax.mail-1.5.3.jar
javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar
jetty-http-9.3.6.v20151106.jar
jetty-io-9.3.6.v20151106.jar
jetty-security-9.3.6.v20151106.jar
jetty-server-9.3.6.v20151106.jar
jetty-servlet-9.3.6.v20151106.jar
jetty-util-9.3.6.v20151106.jar
jetty-webapp-9.3.6.v20151106.jar
jetty-xml-9.3.6.v20151106.jar
log4j-1.2.17.jar
org.apache.jasper.glassfish-2.2.2.v201112011158.jar
slf4 j-api-1.7.13.jar
spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-support-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar
```

Update 2015.12.10:

So I played around a bit with different Jetty Versions.  The original code was using 8.1.17 and I decided to upgrade it to 9.3.6.   So I downgraded it to 9.3.5, but had the same results.  Then I downgraded to 9.2.14 and the problem was resolved.  So Either this is a bug in Jetty 9.3.x ( which would seem unlikely as someone would be using this) or with 9.3 their is a different way to configure it.  I looked for documentation about it be it all shows the same way that I am doing it.